# google actions: how to use custom intents with actions sdk

Tags: actions-on-google

This question is when using google actions with actions SDK. The documentation gives an example of using a custom buy intents as shown

```
{
      "name": "BUY",
      "intent": {
        "name": "com.example.sekai.BUY",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "color",
            "type": "org.schema.type.Color"
          }
        ],
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "find some $org.schema.type.Color:color sneakers",
            "buy some blue suede shoes",
            "get running shoes"
          ]
        }
      },
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "sekaiApp"
      }
}
```

However, the google functions code in nodeJS only invokes the custom logic associated with the `actions.intent.TEXT`.

I found an [article](https://github.com/googlearchive/actionssdk-eliza-nodejs/issues/6) mentioning that state that in actions SDK only inbuilt intents are supported.

**Question: is it possible to set up a custom intent using actions SDK and if so, can a snippet be shared as guidance?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, custom Intents in the Actions SDK are used for *conversation shaping* rather than Intent identification. All spoken or typed inputs are sent as TEXT Intents. Identification is expected to be done with a Natural Language Understanding/Processing system (NLU/NLP), and the Actions SDK does not provide an NLU/NLP.

In the [example you cite](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/define-actions#define_additional_actions), they are specifically talking about deep linking trigger events, although similar concepts apply for other conversational Intents. In each case, the phrases help make sure the correct text is sent to you for you to process.

For example, without these hints, the speech-to-text model could hear the user as saying something like "buy some blue soled shoes" or "get run in shoes". Both of which your system would likely not understand.

If you are looking for an NLP system that will match the phrases (or similar phrases) and parameters with Intents, you can look into something like Dialogflow, which is well integrated with Actions on Google, or you can use any NLP library of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner for the clarity on positioning of actions sdk. The use-case I am exploring is in education where a user can search curriculum based topics using Google DA. I did look at Dialogflow to understand actions but somehow thought that actions sdk gave greater control. Let me revisit that decision. Thanks